# Continuous random variable that is constant for a fraction of the domain

Tags: random-variable, continuous-data

Consider a random variable $X$ defined on $[0,1]$, which is $
X(\omega)=
\begin{cases}
0.5, \omega \in [0,0.5]\\
\omega, \omega \in (0.5,1]
\end{cases}$.
Intuitively, this definition makes sense to me. However, $X$ is $0.5$ for a fixed fraction of the domain. Thus, $\Pr[X = 0.5] = 0.5$, which cannot be true, right? Also, if I'm not mistaken the CDF would not be continuous.

Does this mean there cannot be a continuous random variable which has one value for a fraction of its domain? Or what am I confusing here?

Edit: Sorry I forgot. The pdf of $X$ is the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Is $X(\omega)$ your PDF, i.e. $f_X(x)$?

Comment: $X$ is _not_ a continuous random variable; it is a _mixed_ random variable that takes on values in $[\frac 12,1]$ with a probability _mass_ or _atom_ of $0.5$ at $\frac 12$. The CDF has a _jump_ discontinuity at $\frac 12$ and is _right_-continuous on $[\frac 12, \infty)$.